# python Django ASP.NET Identity password hasher equivalent

Tags: python, asp.net, django, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have setup task to authenticate django application users against .NET Identity database. I found many related topics, but they was either too old or not solving exaclty what I need - password hasher equivalent for Django.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No question I just did this post to share my experience.

Answer (score 2):

So I end up learning this source https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto.cs
And did write my django version. The code works for me with django 2.1.1 and .NET 4.5

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import pbkdf2
import hashlib
from  base64 import b64decode

identity_PasswordHash = "AOOVvPns8Nov6CsJDTAWz+QDOEO2csh60m5aYyX2Vn7LsNDhiiZ5UaSDWr5izwWeHA=="
pwd_plain = 'Hellow123';

def dotnet_identity_check_password(password, hash):
    binsalt = b64decode(hash)[1:17]
    binpwd = b64decode(hash)[17:]
    genpwd = pbkdf2(password, binsalt, 1000, digest=hashlib.sha1, dklen=32)
    if genpwd == binpwd:
       return True
    return False

if dotnet_identity_check_password(pwd_plain,identity_PasswordHash):
     print("OK")
else:
     print("Fail")
```

Answer (score 1):

identity v3 verson:

```
import hashlib
from  base64 import b64decode
def dotnet_identity_v3_check_password(password:str, hash:str)-> bool:
    bhash = b64decode(hash)
    iterCount = readNetworkByteOrder(bhash,5)
    saltSize = readNetworkByteOrder(bhash,9)
    if (saltSize < 128 / 8):
        return False    
    salt = bhash[13:13+saltSize]
    subkeySize = len(bhash) - 13 - saltSize
    if (subkeySize < 128 / 8):
        return False
    expectedSubkey = bhash[13+saltSize:]
    actualSubkey = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, iterCount, subkeySize)   
    if expectedSubkey == actualSubkey:
        return True
    return False
def readNetworkByteOrder( buffer: bytes, offset:int)->int:
    return ((buffer[offset]) << 24) | ((buffer[offset + 1]) << 16) | ((buffer[offset + 2]) << 8) | ((buffer[offset + 3]))
```